# WhenActivated gives Exception on Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, reactiveui

I'm building an app with ReactiveUI (reactiveui-xamforms -7.4.0) and trying to use WhenActivated with ViewModels. I have followed the link https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-activated/ .
I have implemented ISupportsActivation for the ViewModel and also called WhenActivated in the view. The project builds and runs for Xamarin.Droid as expected, However when I try to run Xamarin.iOS project , it throws exception -

> "System.ArgumentException Don't know how to detect when Page is
>   activated/deactivated, you may need to implement
>   IActivationForViewFetcher".

I can find "Xamarin.iOS: Unable to locate assembly 'ReactiveUI.XamForms" in logs. I have tried with various linker options to resolve this but with no success.

Can anyone help on this ?

[Update]: It works using "ReactiveContentPage" instead of "ContentPage".

Comment: Sorry to hear your experiencing difficulties. Can you please upload a sample project onto GitHub so we can ensure the right packages are installed?

Comment: Here is the sample project reproducing the issue. https://github.com/vishalshahi/XamarinApp

Comment: Having the same problem....any news on this bug @GeoffreyHuntley ???